# Flex Module throwing security sandbox violation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I converted a standalone Flex app into a module. Now that it's a module, when I login (and call the backend services), I'm getting a security sandbox violation.

The login handler throws this fault String: 'Send Failed', with a more descriptive: 'Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed:url: 'http://myUrl:8080/AppManager/messagebroker/amf'.

Then the FB console throws an 'unhandled security sandbox violation error'.

Can converting an app into a module cause a sandbox violation?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Because a Flex module must be in the same security domain as the application (SWF) that loads it, when you're using modules in an AIR application any module SWF must be located in the same directory as the main application SWF or one of its subdirectories, which ensures that like the main application SWF, the module SWF is in the AIR application security sandbox. One way to verify this is to ensure that a relative URL for the module's location doesn't require "../" ("up one level") notation to navigate outside the application directory or one of its subdirectories.

Comment: ^ that's from the adobe docs, also curious though does it make a request for the crossdomain.xml file, debugging with Firebug or Charles will probably help to see a bit more granular what is and what isn't happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making extensive use of modules and haven't run into this. There are memory issues I ran into that I had to fix by actually declaring an instance of the modules in the main modules...I didn't have to create an instance, just declare a variable to get the linkage right, then have all the other modules compile against that main module. Memory errors went away, and all the other modules were much smaller too.

Comment: @shaunhusain: my shell points to the modules a la: testModuleInfo = ModuleManager.getModule('assets/modules/TestModule.swf');...so I'm pretty sure that I'm in the same security domain as the shell. However, the module that I'm having problems with loads its config XML a la: new URLRequest( './assets/modules/TestConfig.xml' ) );      Could this be the problem? And, if so, how?

Comment: Is that loading from a file or web server? And a messagebroker message usually means there's a BlazeDS or something like it involved.

Comment: Yes, I'm using blazeds and the file is loaded from a server.

Comment: I think shaun is on the right track, have you tried removing the ".", because it looks like the rest of the path is the same as the SWF's is.

Comment: I just did and it's still throwing me an error when I'm hitting the Blaze DS gateway. The other modules I load in use either webservices or other remote objects but the one I'm having problems with is the only one that loads an external config XML file to determine the endpoint (blaze ds gateway). Could this be an issue where the first module loaded determines the remote object gateway for all following loaded modules?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know the URL that the page the hosts the main module determines security domain, trying to go anywhere else would require crossdomain.xml, or setting up a proxy within BlazeDS itself.

Comment: I looked it up and there appears to be a bug with the network monitor in flashbuilder 4. keep your eyes peeled!